# куда vs где in the following sentence

Tags: грамматика

Which form is correct:

`Куда Паша положил учебники?` or `Где Паша положил учебники?`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the past form is ***положил***, with л in both cases.
With that in mind, if you consult any словарь сочетаемости, you'll find the following:

Положить кого-что-л. ***к у д а*** : (предлог «в» с вин.) ~~ в стол, в
шкаф, в холодильник, в коробку, в ящик, в портфель, в чемодан, в
кошелёк, в конверт, в карман ...; (предлог «на» с вин.) ~ на кровать,
на диван, на но- снлки, на стул, на стол, на шкаф, на подоконник,
на пол, на место, на колени, на плечо ...; (предлог «за» с вин.) ~ за
окно, за дверь, за шкаф, за зеркало ...; (предлог «под» с вин.) ~ под
шкаф, под стол, под кровать.

Answer (score 4):

There's a difference in context.

Indeed, куда Паша положил учебники - в стол, в шкаф, в холодильник.

But, где Паша положил учебники - в спальне, в кабинете, в столовой.

I.e. `где` takes a different object case, and the destination should be a *place* one can walk into and put something down in. It should also be a large object (a stack of textbooks, for instance) and should ideally be put directly on the floor.

P. S. куда Паша положил учебники - в стол в кабинете, в столовой в холодильник.

Answer (score 2):

В русском языке нет особых правил построения предложений и, поэтому, оба варианты правильные. Но лучше выглядит «Куда Паша положил учебники?».

*(In Russian, there are no special rules for constructing sentences and, therefore, both options are correct. But it looks better “Куда Паша положил учебники?”.)* — `translated using Google Translate.`